# Create and use HTML full text search index (C++)

Tags: c++, html, visual-c++, full-text-search

I need to create a search index for a collection of HTML pages.

I have no experience in implementing a search index at all, so any general information how to build one, what information to store, how to implement advanced searches such as "entire phrase", ranking of results etc.

I'm not afraid to build it myself, though I'd be happy to reuse an existing component (or use one to get started with a prototype). I am looking for a solution accessible from C++, preferrably without requiring additional installations at runtime. The content is static (so it makes sense to aggregate search information), but a search might have to accumulate results from multiple such repositories.

---

I can make a few educated guesses, though: create a map `word ==>  pages` for all (relevant) words, a rank can be assigned to the mapping by promincence (h1 > h2 > ... > `<p>`) and proximity to top. Advanced searches could be built on top of that: searching for phrase `"homo sapiens"` could list all pages that contain `"homo"` and `"sapiens"`, then scan all pages returned for locations where they occur together. However, there are a lot of problematic scenarios and unanswered questions, so I am looking for references to what should be a huge amount of existing work that somehow escapes my google-fu.

---

**[edit for bounty]**
The best resource I found until now [is this](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/php_tip_how_extract_keywords_web_page) and the links from there. 
I do have an imlementation roadmap for an experimental system, however, I am still looking for:

- Reference material regarding index creation and individual steps
- available implementations of individual steps
- reusable implementations (with above environment restrictions)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This process is generally known as [information retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval).  You'll probably find [this online book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html) helpful.

## Existing libraries

Here are two existing solutions that can be fully integrated into an application without requiring a separate process (I believe both will compile with VC++).

[Xapian](http://xapian.org/docs/) is mature and may do much of what you need, from indexing to ranked retrieval.  Separate HTML parsing would be required because, AFAIK, it does not parse html (it has a companion program [Omega](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html), which is a front end for indexing web sites).

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is a index/searching Apache library in Java, with an official pre-release C version [lucy](http://lucene.apache.org/lucy/), and an unofficial C++ version [CLucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/).

## Implementing information retrieval

If the above options are not viable for some reason, here's some info on the individual steps of building and using an index.  Custom solutions can go from simple to very sophisticated, depending what you need for your application.  I've broken the process into 5 steps

1. HTML processing
2. Text processing
3. Indexing
4. Retrieval
5. Ranking

### HTML Processing

There are two approaches here

- **Stripping**  The page you referred to discusses a technique generally known as stripping, which involves removing all the html elements that won't be displayed and translating others to their display form.  Personally, I'd preprocess using perl and index the resulting text files.  But for an integrated solution, particularly one where you want to record significance tags (e.g. <h1>, <h2>), you probably want to role your own.  [Here is a partial implementation](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/tic/tic0180.shtml#Heading471) of a C++ stripping routine (appears in *Thinking in C++* , final version of book [here](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html#HTMLFormat)), that you could build from.
- **Parsing** A level up in complexity from stripping is html parsing, which would help in your case for recording significance tags.  However, a good C++ HTML parser is [hard to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser). Some options might be [htmlcxx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlcxx/) (never used it, but active and looks promising) or [hubbub](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/hubbub/) (C library, part of NetSurf, but claims to be portable).

  If you are dealing with XHTML or are willing to use an HTML-to-XML converter, you can use one of the many available XML parsers.  But again, HTML-to-XML converters are hard to find, the only one I know of is [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).  In addition to conversion to XHTML, its primary purpose is to fix missing/broken tags, and it [has an API](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/api/) that could possibly be used to integrate it into an application.  Given XHTML documents, there are many good XML parsers, e.g. [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) and [tinyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/).

### Text Processing

For English at least, processing text to words is pretty straight forward.  There are a couple of complications when search is involved though.

- **Stop words** are words known a priori not to provide a useful distinction between documents in the set, such as articles and propositions.  Often these words are not indexed and filtered from query streams.  There are many stop word lists available on the web, such as this [one](http://www.lextek.com/manuals/onix/stopwords1.html).
- **Stemming** involves preprocessing documents and queries to identify the root of each word to better generalize a search.  E.g. searching for "foobarred" should yield "foobarred", "foobarring", and "foobar".  The index can be built and searched on roots alone.  The two general approaches to stemming are dictionary based (lookups from word ==> root) and algorithm based.  The Porter algorithm is very common and several implementations are available, e.g. [C++ here](http://www.oleandersolutions.com/stemming/stemming.html) or [C here](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/).  Stemming in the [Snowball C library](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) supports several languages.
- **[Soundex encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)**  One method to make search more robust to spelling errors is to encode words with a phonetic encoding.  Then when queries have phonetic errors, they will still map directly to indexed words.  There are a lot of implementations around, [here's one](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Soundex).

### Indexing

The map word ==> page data structure is known as an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).  Its inverted because its often generated from a forward index of page ==> words.  Inverted indexes generally come in two flavors: *inverted file index*, which map words to each document they occur in, and *full inverted index*, which map words to each position in each document they occur in.

The important decision is what backend to use for the index, some possibilities are, in order of ease of implementation:

1. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [Berkly DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) - both of these are database engines with C++ APIs that integrated into a project without requiring a separate server process.  Persistent databases are essentially files, so multiple index sets can be search by just changing the associated file. Using a DBMS as a backend simplifies index creation, updating and searching.
2. In memory data structure - if your using a inverted file index that is not prohibitively large (memory consumption and time to load), this could be implemented as a `std::map<std::string,word_data_class>`, using [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for persistence.
3. On disk data structure - I've heard of blazingly fast results using memory mapped files for this sort of thing, YMMV.  Having an inverted file index would involve having two index files, one representing words with something like `struct {char word[n]; unsigned int offset; unsigned int count; };`, and the second representing (word, document) tuples with just `unsigned int`s (words implicit in the file offset).  The `offset` is the file offset for the first document id for the word in the second file, `count` is the number of document ids associate with that word (number of ids to read from the second file).  Searching would then reduce to a binary search through the first file with a pointer into a memory mapped file.  The down side is the need to pad/truncate words to get a constant record size.

The procedure for indexing depends on which backend you use.  The classic algorithm for generating a inverted file index ([detailed here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html)) begins with reading through each document and extending a list of (page id, word) tuples, ignoring duplicate words in each document.  After all documents are processed, sort the list by word, then collapsed into (word, (page id1, page id2, ...)).

The [mifluz](http://www.gnu.org/software/mifluz/) gnu library implements inverted indexes w/ storage, but without document or query parsing. GPL, so may not be a viable option, but will give you an idea of the complexities involved for an inverted index that supports a large number of documents.

### Retrieval

A very common method is boolean retrieval, which is simply the union/intersection of documents indexed for each of the query words that are joined with or/and, respectively.  These operations are efficient if the document ids are stored in sorted order for each term, so that algorithms like `std::set_union` or `std::set_intersection` can be applied directly.

There are variations on retrieval, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Model_types) has an overview, but standard boolean is good for many/most application.

### Ranking

There are many methods for ranking the documents returned by boolean retrieval. Common methods are based on the bag of words model, which just means that the relative position of words is ignored.  The general approach is to score each retrieved document relative to the query, and rank documents based on their calculated score.  There are many scoring methods, but a good starting place is the *term frequency-inverse document frequency* formula.

The idea behind this formula is that if a query word occurs frequently in a document, that document should score higher, but a word that occurs in many documents is less informative so this word should be down weighted.  The formula is, over query terms i=1..N and document j

score[j] = sum_over_i(word_freq[i,j] * inv_doc_freq[i])

where the word_freq[i,j] is the number of occurrences of word i in document j, and

inv_doc_freq[i] = log(M/doc_freq[i])

where M is the number of documents and doc_freq[i] is the number of documents containing word i.  Notice that words that occur in all documents will not contribute to the score. A more complex scoring model that is widely used is [BM25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_relevance_model_%28BM25%29), which is included in both Lucene and Xapian.

Often, effective ranking for a particular domain is obtained by adjusting by trial and error.  A starting place for adjusting rankings by heading/paragraph context could be inflating word_freq for a word based on heading/paragraph context, e.g. 1 for a paragraph, 10 for a top level heading.  For some other ideas, you might find [this paper](http://newton.eecs.cwru.edu/papers/sigir07-final.pdf) interesting, where the authors adjusted BM25 ranking for positional scoring (the idea being that words closer to the beginning of the document are more relevant than words toward the end).

Objective quantification of ranking performance is obtained by precision-recall curves or mean average precision, detailed [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-ranked-retrieval-results-1.html).  Evaluation requires an ideal set of queries paired with all the relevant documents in the set.

Comment: Xapian is the bomb, especially for non-Java environments.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Which lead me into javascript.

Comment: @academicRobot : Nice Description, Further I was looking at Code of Telegram (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) and understand that they have used some custom c++ solution similar to Lucene. Do you have any insight on that too ?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size and number of the static pages, you might want to look at an already existent search solution.

*"How do you implement full-text search for that 10+ million row table, keep up with the load, and stay relevant? [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) is good at those kinds of riddles."*

I would choose the [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) engine for `full text searching`. The licence is `GPL` but the also have a `commercial` version available. It is meant to be run stand-alone [[2]](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-searchd), but it can also be embedded into applications by extracting the needed functionality (be it `indexing`[[1]](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-indexer), `searching` [[3]](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-search), `stemming`, etc).

The data should be obtained by parsing the input `HTML` files and transforming them to `plain-text` by using a parser like [libxml2's HTMLparser](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html)  (I haven't used it, but they say it can parse even malformed HTML). If you aren't bound to `C/C++` you could take a look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

After obtaining the plain-texts, you could store them in a database like `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL`. If you want to keep everything embedded you should go with [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Note that `Sphinx` doesn't work out-of-the-box with `sqlite`, but there is an attempt to add support ([sphinx-sqlite3](http://github.com/aughey/sphinx-sqlite3)).

Comment: +1 for libxml, I thought it had gnome dependencies, but it does not, detailed [here](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would attack this with a little sqlite database. You could have tables for 'page', 'term' and 'page term'. 'Page' would have columns like id, text, title and url. 'Term' would have a column containing a word, as well as the primary ID. 'Page term' would have foreign keys to a page ID and a term ID, and could also store the weight, calculated from the distance from the top and the number of occurrences (or whatever you want).

Perhaps a more efficient way would be to only have two tables - 'page' as before, and 'page term' which would have the page ID, the weight, and a hash of the term word.

An example query - you want to search for "foo". You hash "foo", then query all page term rows that have that term hash. Sort by descending weight and show the top ten results.

I think this should query reasonably quickly, though it obviously depends on the number and size of the pages in question. Sqlite isn't difficult to bundle and shouldn't need an additional installation.

Answer (score 2):

Ranking pages is the really tricky bit here. With a *large* sample of pages you can use links quite a lot in working out ranks. Other wise you need to check how words seem to be placed, and also making sure your engine doesn't get fooled by 'dictionary' pages.

Good luck!

Comment: I expect to get good results with ranking word/page entries by tag and position, pages could be further ranked by "links to" and other measures. When all else fails, I *can* rely on page keywords (unlike internet search engines).